# Expandable div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got the expandable part of things working just fine, but I'm trying to find out if there's a way to make my "read more..." link disappear after it's clicked. I've gotten most of my code and troubleshooting from here (StackOverflow), but I just can't find a way for it to disappear.

Code is as follows:

```
<p style="text-align: center; font-size:18px; font face=nerislight; color:#009cdc">Test title test title test title</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a){
var e=document.getElementById(a);
var i = document.getElementById(a + '_image');
if(!e)return true;
if(e.style.display=="none"){
e.style.display="block"} else {
e.style.display="none"}
return false;
}
</script>

Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy </p>

<p style="text-align: center; font-size:14px; font face=nerislight"><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="return toggleMe('landworks')">Read more...</a>

<div id="landworks" style="display:none;">Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion </p>

<strong>More Expansion</strong>Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion </p>

<p style="text-align: center;">Call to Action</p>

<div class="mk-button-align center"><a href="http://atestpage.com" id="123" class="mk-button dark button-190 light-color  mk-shortcode three-dimension small  ">Contact us today!</a></div>

<style type="text/css">
.button-190 {
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;

    }

    .button-190 {
            background-color:#009cdc;

    }

     .button-190:hover {
            background-color:#0091cd;

    }
    .button-190.three-dimension  {
         box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #007db0;
    }
    .button-190.three-dimension:active  {
         box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #007db0;
    } 
</style>
</div>
```

Basically, I want it so that if someone were to click the "read more..." that it just disappears and looks like normal copy. As it sits now, after clicking the "read more" it's still on the page creating a weird break in the text. Can anyone help??

PS: I would love to put it JSFiddle for y'all to see, but I don't know how. New to javascript...

Comment: I have this working on an active website, but I'd rather not share private corporate info unless I have to...

If you want to see it live, let me know and I can send you a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the "read more" paragraph before you process the `toggleMe` function:

```
onclick="this.style.display='none';return toggleMe('landworks')"
```

You can see it working with your code in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p8v9qpdL/

Comment: This one looks like the easiest fix for my not-so-clean coding. Thanks!

Comment: As I was going sleep last night it popped into my head that it had to do with the onclick function, I just didn't know the syntax. 

Worked perfectly! Without having to rewrite the code...

Answer (score 0):

This code should so the job:
https://jsfiddle.net/maxim_mazurok/76kjpy27/

```
<p style="text-align: center; font-size:18px; font face=nerislight; color:#009cdc">Test title test title test title</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a){
var e=document.getElementById(a);
var i = document.getElementById(a + '_image');
var rm = document.getElementById('read-more');
rm.style.display="none";
if(!e)return true;
if(e.style.display=="none"){
e.style.display="block"} else {
e.style.display="none"}
return false;
}
</script>

Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy Test copy </p>

<p style="text-align: center; font-size:14px; font face=nerislight"><a id="read-more" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="return toggleMe('landworks')">Read more...</a>

<div id="landworks" style="display:none;">Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion </p>

<strong>More Expansion</strong>Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion Expansion </p>

<p style="text-align: center;">Call to Action</p>

<div class="mk-button-align center"><a href="http://atestpage.com" id="123" class="mk-button dark button-190 light-color  mk-shortcode three-dimension small  ">Contact us today!</a></div>

<style type="text/css">
.button-190 {
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;

    }

    .button-190 {
            background-color:#009cdc;

    }

     .button-190:hover {
            background-color:#0091cd;

    }
    .button-190.three-dimension  {
         box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #007db0;
    }
    .button-190.three-dimension:active  {
         box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #007db0;
    } 
</style>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a really simple version of this, so it'd be easier to isolate the problem.

What it does is listens for a click, then changes the height of the article (which contains everything else) and makes the button disappear.

The styles are overflow: hidden (to hide stuff that overflows the height in this case) and a static height.

```
read_more.addEventListener('click', function () {
    main.style.height = 'auto';
    read_more.style.display = 'none';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/snlacks/5f2qpx04/

Answer (score 0):

Put and id on the  element and a corresponding id on the content div, with standardized suffixes on your ids.  Pass the prefix for these ids into your toggle_me function, and change the visibility of both the link and the content at the same time:

```
<a id='landmark-read-more' onclick='return toggle_me("landmark")'>Read more...</a>
<div id='landmark-content'>Content</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a){
  var contentDiv=document.getElementById(a+'-content');
  var toggleLink=document.getElementById(a+'-toggle');
  if(!contentDiv)return true;
  if(contentDiv.style.display=="none"){
    contentDiv.style.display="block";
    toggleLink.style.display="none";
  } else {
    contentDiv.style.display="none";
    toggleLink.style.display="block";
  }
  return false;
}

</script>
```

As an aside: there's no link for the user to roll up the expansion, so there's no real need right now for the toggle function to include setting the display to none.

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar div expansion for our website ([live example](http://www.maurices.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=58080716)). I don't have the clickable text hidden in the live version, but I just added this to my jQuery and it hid the targeted class:

```
        $('.yourClassHere').toggle();
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paulmz/8uvj3d79/1/) with this in use plus a bit of a simplified expanding area.

Comment: Except that I answered the question using jQuery... maybe it will help someone else someday.